# Magento: Auto Add Gift Certificate to Cart Every $X Amount

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

We have a website that we are trying add a gift certificate to the cart for every $100 someone spends (i.e. a customer gets a $10 gift certificate for every $100 they spend). We are currently using Magento 1.6.1 and Unirgy Gift Cerificate to do our gift certificate system. Does anyone have a better solution or a way to use our current system to do what we want?

I have looked into a whole bunch of Add to Cart extensions, but all of them don't seem to allow me to add a gift certificate to the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the extension is paid so I cannot help you much here but: If you know how the gift card is added to cart (check extension code to find out) you could try adding observer using 'checkout_cart_product_add_after' event. On how to add events, check here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

In the observer method, check how much $$$ the cart does have by getting quote e.g:

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote();

and gathering grand total (getGrandTotal metod I guess)

and add as many coupons as you would like ($total/100 = $gifcard_amount) and then reuse the code by using

```
for ($i=0;$i<$giftcard_amount;$i++){
//giftcard add logic
}
```

Hope this will get you started.